# How to reference another EC2 instance, which may be restarted or even have another instance started?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Consider an server `ec2-50-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, which is not publicly available and which does not have an elastic IP address. I cannot assign it an Elastic IP address as I don't have any more addresses to assign (used all 5 already on publicly-available servers).

The publicly-available servers need to access a service on `ec2-50-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. However, if I restart that server then it may receive a different address and I'll have to update 20 websites across 5 webservers with the new address. Is there any way to refer to the `ec2-50-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com` server which will persist even if I restart that server, considering that I have no more Elastic IP addresses to assign to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the the best way to refer to other instances in AWS is to use [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (VPC). In VPC each machine gets a static internal IP address, which persists for the lifetime of the instance. In fact in VPC one can configure full networking!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to refer to

Key word "refer to" -- indeed, there is... a DNS `CNAME`.

Whether your DNS is in Route 53 or elsewhere, a CNAME record refers a system asking for a particular host by name, to a different host -- also by name.

Let's say, for example, that the service this system provides is the generation of reports.  In the "example.com" domain...

```
reports  IN  CNAME   ec2-50-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

Any machine looking up "reports.example.com" from the DNS will be referred to the hostname ec2-50-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com which will of course resolve to the machine's IP address.

If the machine's IP address (and therefore, in AWS, its hostname) changes because the instance was terminated or failed or replaced, you only have to update the information in one place -- the DNS.  The systems that need to access this system would be configured with "reports.example.com" instead of the other hostname, so they wouldn't have to be maintained individually.

If you are using Route 53, it's also possible to configure Route 53 to actually give out a different answer using [failover routing](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/02/11/announcing-dns-failover-for-route-53/) with [health checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) and divert requests elsewhere when the instance isn't working properly.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this approach is DNS caching: it could conceivably be quite some time between "I've updated the DNS" and "The server accessing the resource updates its DNS cache". Otherwise, I do agree that DNS is the right approach, that is quite what it was invented for. However, current DNS implementations take the stance that the SND records are rarely updated and thus cachable long term (hours), which may not be the case in this use case.

Comment: I set my TTLs to values between 60 and 300 seconds in the zone files and the only inappropriate caching I encounter is with web browsers, not server components, so your suggestion that "current DNS implementations" exhibit the behavior you describe seems like a significant overstatement.  A DNS component that doesn't honor TTLs is broken.

Comment: If DNS propagation is actually a problem you could put the EC2 instance behind an Elastic Load Balancer. That way the DNS would not need to change, and you could just replace the instance attached to the ELB.

Comment: @Peter makes a good point... and with the [recent announcement that ELB now supports version 1 of the `PROXY` protocol for TCP listeners,](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/07/30/elastic-load-balancing-now-supports-proxy-protocol/) any TCP-based service that can also understand that protocol can now discover the IP and port of the machine initiating the inbound connection -- not just HTTP(S).  That opens up a lot of new possibilities with ELB that didn't make sense, before.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon will not give you any difficulty at all if you simply request more Elastic IPs.  It's right here: [Request to Increase Elastic IP Address Limit](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/eip_limit_request/)